# Display soft hyphens in VIM

Tags: vim, fonts, unicode

How do I get (G)VIM under Ubuntu 14.04 to display soft hyphens in a UTF-8 encoded text file?

The `encoding` and the `fileenconding` settings are both set to `utf-8`, and characters like the German umlauts (äöü) are displayed correctly. In place of soft hyphens (Unicode `00ad`, html `&shy;`) however, I see only a blank where I'd expect a minus sign. I have tried various settings for `guifont`, but neither Anonymous Pro Minus, nor Courier New, nor Liberation Mono seem to do the trick. The same fonts work nicely for jEdit.

Comment: It works for me in Windows. If I go into insert mode and press `control-v` then type `u00ad` I get what looks like a version of a dash character. (I can't seem to paste it here.)

Comment: I can reproduce this with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: So are you saying it's a Vim bug? Or is this an example of other applications searching various fonts for a glyph when Vim stubbornly uses the font as set.

Comment: Ben, how can I find that out? I would'Ve guessed that the fonts I used are utf-8-complete to a high percentage, and representing the soft hyphen with a dash character seems to be an obvious choice. So how do I detect where the error lies?

Answer (score 0):

This should do, where the soft-hyphen is between the brackets:

```
syntax match Entity "­ " conceal cchar=⌿
set conceallevel=2
```

In Vim the soft-hyphen can be generated with the digraph: `ctrl_k + - -`